# how to call a particular method from bin/console command

Tags: php, symfony

I need to run the controller method every 2 hours. I read somewhere that you need to create a command and run this command by using CRON. It is correct?

```
MY COMMAND:
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class RunCommand extends Command
{
    // the name of the command (the part after "bin/console")
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:run';

    protected function configure()
    {
        // ...
    }


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        echo 'BEGIN';

        $controller = new \AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController();
        $controller->storeAction();

        echo 'END';
    }
}


MY CONTROLLER:
/**
 * @Route("/to-db", name="to-db")
 */
public function storeAction()
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $data = new Skuska();
    $data->setName('Keyboard');
    $entityManager->persist($data);
    $entityManager->flush();

    // die();
}
```

My error: In ControllerTrait.php line 424: Call to a member function has() on null

Is my code correct? How do I run a method using cron?

I don't want to use another bundle. I want to program it myself

Comment: Thats probably not the way you instantiate controllers. Honestly controller Is probably too High layer to use in Console command.

Comment: how do I program it? how to call method?

Comment: controllers are for requests. if the functionality inside a controller should also be available otherwise, it would be smart to put it in a service instead. also, you should look up how to do dependency injection in commands (in symfony 4.0 you would just add the service in the command's constructor and store it in a property for later use). also controller actions (with routes) should always return a response.

Comment: You should move you controller logic into a service an call it inside your command as previous comment says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should move the logic out of the controller and into a service, and use that service both in the command and in the controller.

With the default service autoloading configuration, you don't even have to care about your service declarations. Your command will automatically be a service, and you can inject other services into it.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html

For controllers, you don't even need to use a specific constructor.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services

```php
<?php
// AppBundle/Service/StoreService.php

use AppBundle\Entity\Skuska;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class StoreService
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * StoreService constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = new Skuska();
        $data->setName('Keyboard');
        $this->entityManager->persist($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

}
```

```php
<?php
// AppBundle/Controller/StoreController.php

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Service\StoreService;

class StoreController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/to-db", name="to-db")
     * @param StoreService $storeService
     * @return Response
     */
    // Hinting to you service like this should be enough for autoloading.
    // No need for a specific constructor here.
    public function storeAction(StoreService $storeService)
    {
        $storeService->store();
        return new Response(
        // Return something in you response.
        );
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
// AppBundle/Command/RunCommand.php

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use AppBundle\Service\StoreService;

class RunCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'app:run';

    /** @var StoreService */
    protected $storeService;

    /**
     * RunCommand constructor.
     * @param StoreService $storeService
     */
    public function __construct(StoreService $storeService)
    {
        $this->storeService = $storeService;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        echo 'BEGIN';

        $this->storeService->store();

        echo 'END';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an error message: 
In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 37:
  Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Service\StoreService": argument "$entityManager" of method "__construct()" has type "AppBundle\Service\EntityManager" but this class was not found.

Comment: If you copied my example without changing anything, you will have missing `uses` at the top of your class.
You need to add `use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;`.

Comment: I added uses and file paths to the examples. Be sure to check that they match your directory structure and framework version.

Comment: I have an error message: There are no commands defined in the "app" namespace.
Did you mean this? doctrine:mapping
My symfony is 3.4

Comment: I just realized that the namespace in your code snippet is `AppBundle\Command`. You need to use that instead of `app\Command`. I'll change my example to reflect that. What version of Symfony are you using?